# How to avoid Mono ADO.NET serving wrong results to requests after one times out?

Tags: sql-server, mono, ado.net

On the .NET Framework version 4

I'm seeing a possible concurrency issue in the **SQL Server ADO.NET** implementation on **mono 4.2.2** that manifests when queries are cancelled or time out on the client, using the `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader` api.

To reproduce the issue seen in the field:

1. I run start 3 new timed tasks concurrently every second that run 3 - 5 relatively small queries that complete and return (all using `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader`), this runs as expected.
2. Then I add a long running query to the test run, set to execute every 65 seconds but cancel after 60 seconds. It would take longer than 60 seconds for the query to complete so gets cancelled every time (using `SqlCommand.Cancel()`).
3. After running for several minutes, suddenly most of the attempts to iterate the `SqlDataReader` returned error because the expected fields are not present on the returned rows, so when the data layer tries to access them by name, there is an exception.

Adding logging code to print the fields on the row indicate that they are from another query that is being run as part of the test, so one that is either running concurrently or very recently.

Once this problem occurs for one query, it happens very frequently indeed, in fact most queries fail. In the field, even services that were only trying to service 5 or so queries a minute were returning the wrong `recordsets` back for most queries.

Restarting the process fixes the problem.

FYI

1. A new connection, command and reader object are instantiated per query, and are used withing their own 'using' blocks.
2. Default connection pooling for ADO.NET is being used
3. Most connections are to the same DB, there is a seperate connection made to another DB on another server once per task run but this is always completed successfully.
4. The code is mature and in use in production on Windows .NET framework systems without issue, and running the same tests on Windows .NET framework cannot reproduce the problem, so it is unlikely to be an issue across both platforms.

Has anyone else seen this and can tell me what I might be doing wrong? Would simply disabling connection pooling be a (temporary) workaround for this problem?

Comment: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11405 found this, originally reported 2013

Comment: good that you found the bug tracker, stackoverflow is for questions, not for bugs, hence downvoting your question

Comment: The question was asking is there a known work around in common usage, not reporting the bug. I thought since it is a critical bug that is not too difficult to reproduce there might be other people out there working around it already.

Comment: in open source, most people fix bugs, not workaround them

Comment: In industry, most people have these inconvenient things called 'deadlines'. This sometimes means we need a working solution quicker than we can: Pull the source, get it building, understand the overall implementation, find the bug, fix the bug, unit test the fix, regression test the huge number of potential knock on issues the could arise from changing such a core library, etc, etc. I fully intend either as part of my work or personally to fix the bug, but I think it's perfectly legitimate to ask if there is a workaround to get us up and running in the interim.

Comment: I know what a deadline means, but trying to look for a workaround for something you still don't know if it's hard to fix, sounds lazy to me

Answer (score 2):

Following further testing, explicitly disabling connection pooling does in fact work around this issue, but of course this comes with additional overhead, especially for applications with a high frequency of queries

Comment: This question and answer set need some serious upvotes - this is a pretty critical problem for anybody doing something fairly normal with a website or api: making concurrent requests to a database. Not only is it really difficult to debug this problem because it fails more or less silently if you're executing the same query over and over again with different parameters, figuring it out would require testing the framework itself. This fix (above) worked for me - append `Pooling=false` to the connection string, but is far from ideal for the reasons stated above.